# biblatex: postnote behavior

Tags: biblatex, citing

With `style=authoryear`, `biblatex` has this neat feature of automatically adding "p. " or "pp. " before page numbers. My problem is that if I add a further comment after the page number such as ", emphasis added", I lose this feature (which makes my citations inconsistent to each other). Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{referencia.bib}
@misc{john-73,
author = {John, S.},
year = {1973},
title = {The best book ever},
}
\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{referencia.bib}

\begin{document}

``Some quotation'' \citep[43]{john-73}.

``Some quotation'' \citep[see][43]{john-73}.

``Some \emph{quotation}'' \citep[][43, emphasis added]{john-73}.

 \end{document}
```

And here is my ouput:

> “Some quotation” (John, 1973, p. 43).
>
> “Some quotation” (see John, 1973, p. 43)
>
> “Some *quotation*” (John, 1973, 43, emphasis added).

The symbol "p. " disappears in the third citation. So, my question is this: how can I preserve "p. " while adding postnotes such as "emphasis added"? Is there a standard way of doing that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`biblatex` will normally detect if the postnote argument of a citation is a single page or a page range and will add the appropriate prefix. This also works for, e.g., Roman numerals, but not for numbers plus text, as in your third citation. In these cases, you have to manually add `\pno` (which prints the single page prefix of the current language) or `\ppno` (which prints the page range prefix). Using a non-breakable space, you should write your third citation as

```
``Some \emph{quotation}'' \citep[][\pno~43, emphasis added]{john-73}.
```

See section 3.14.3 (*Page Numbers in Citations*) of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 3):

From `biblatex` 3.13 (2019-08-17) onwards, you can use the macro `\pnfmt` instead of `\pno` and `\ppno`. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/870.

`\pnfmt` formats its argument exactly like `biblatex` formats the complete `postnote` argument. So if `\pnfmt` contains only a page range and the `postnote` format adds a page prefix, you will get a page prefix from `\pnfmt`. In that case `\pnfmt` will automatically choose the correct form of the page prefix ("p."/`\pno` or "pp."/`\ppno`), add the required space and normalise the range delimiters. Furthermore, the command is useful for uniformity in case you decide to modify the `postnote` field format.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

%\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite[\pnfmt{380-382}, emphasis added]{sigfridsson}

\autocite[\pnfmt{381}, emphasis added]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, pp. 380–382, emphasis added)//(Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 381, emphasis added)]

See also [Biblatex citepages=omit not working when postnote has text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531646/35864).