# Biblatex citepages=omit not working when postnote has text

Tags: biblatex

I am working with philosophy-verbose style with `citepages=omit`.

Sometimes I need comment in the footnotes after reference. Writing just `text.\footcite[22, textual comment]{bertram}` outputs footnote

> Bertram Aaron, Wentworth Richard, "Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces", J. Amer. Math. Soc., 9, 2 (1996), pp. 529-571, 22, textual comment.

I don't need `pagetotal` and it is absent without text in the postnote:
`text.\footcite[22]{bertram}` results in footnote

> Bertram Aaron, Wentworth Richard, "Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces", J. Amer. Math. Soc., 9, 2 (1996), p. 22.

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64474/142952) showed to me how add p. before page number, but `pagetotal` field that I don't need is there:
`text.\footcite[\pno~22, textual comment]{bertram}` results footnote

> Bertram Aaron, Wentworth Richard, "Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces", J. Amer. Math. Soc., 9, 2 (1996), pp. 529-571, p. 22, textual comment.

Now I am using `\cite` inside `\footnot`: `text.\footnote{\cite[22]{bertram}, textual comment}` to get desired footnote

> Bertram Aaron, Wentworth Richard, "Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces", J. Amer. Math. Soc., 9, 2 (1996), p. 22, textual comment.

Is this intended behaviour that `citepages=omit` is not working in such conditions or I am doing something wrong?

**MVE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backref=true,citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
text.\footcite[\pno~22, textual comment]{bertram}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional. `citepages=omit` tests if the `postnote` is a page range and only suppresses the `pages` field in that case. The idea being that in other cases it can not be guaranteed that the `postnote` contains page references that supersede the info in the  `pages` field.

Following discussions in [2 exact page numbers in footnotes biblatex-sbl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506360/35864) and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/918, the next version of `biblatex` (v3.15) will have two new commands `\NumsCheckSetup` and `\PagesCheckSetup` that can be used to define a command that lets you hide additional text in the footnote from the macro that tests if we are dealing with a page range.

So we can define a new macro `\hidefromifpages` that simply expands to its argument, but then we redefine it to hide its argument when `\ifpages` does its text. That means that if the rest of the `postnote` outside `\hidefromifpages` is a page range, the `postnote` field still passes the test.

Instead of manual `\pno~` it is more convenient to use `\pnfmt` introduced in version 3.13 (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/870).

The MWE contains two code blocks: The first block defines `\PagesCheckSetup` and sets it up for `\pnfmt`. That code block will be superfluous in `biblatex` 3.15 or above, since it will be contained in the `biblatex` core. In the MWE the block is coded in a way that will cause it to raise an error in newer `biblatex` version to remind you that it should be removed.

The second code block sets up `\hidefromifpages`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backref=true,citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% In biblatex 3.15 and above
% \NumsCheckSetup and \PagesCheckSetup are part of the biblatex core.
% The following lines will then throw an error.
% Just remove them if that happens.
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\NumsCheckSetup}{\appto\blx@hook@ifnums}
\newrobustcmd*{\PagesCheckSetup}{\appto\blx@hook@ifpages}
\PagesCheckSetup{\let\pnfmt\@firstofone}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hidefromifpages}[1]{#1}
\PagesCheckSetup{\let\hidefromifpages\@gobble}
\makeatother


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
text.\footcite[\pnfmt{380--381}\hidefromifpages{, textual comment}]{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde, “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”, Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19, 4 (1998), doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P, pp. 380-381, textual comment.]

Comment: Oh, I'm glad to see you are also finding use for `\pnfmt`. :)

Comment: @moewe thank you for such detailed answer. But your code isn't working for me, it throws errors "! Undefined control sequence.
l.15107 \blx @processoptions" and so on when using in my version of style or with untouched philosophy-verbose and with your MVE.

Comment: It generates dvi file with with such text: `@processoptions 
heckoptions@global @ 
 ff 
 maxnamesaxcitenames@ 
ff minnamesincitenames@ 
ff maxitemsaxitems@ 
ff minitemsinitems  
@donameparts niquelistpt@uniquelist@minyear on?opt'uniquelist=minyear' re-  
quires 'labeldateparts'.Setting 'uniquelist=true' @dodates uxwritemain-  
aux\abx@aux@refcontextefcontext@context heckencoding blinput axsection@ nf@refsec  
nf@refsegopreamblecmds` in the upper part of a page and `1 sigfridsson.` in the footnote. Maybe this will be useful for understanding what is going on.

Comment: @moewe Sorry, your code is working with untouched philology-verbose style, but not with modified by me. And there were quite long list of modifications... Maybe these errors can say to you what can be wrong and where I should search for cause?

Comment: @Maras Sorry, I have no idea why you would get those errors. If you can come up with a minimal example that reproduces the errors, I'll be happy to look at them. Just open a new question. Was `! Undefined control sequence. l.15107 \blx @processoptions` the very first error, or was there one before that? That error looks like the category code of `@` is wrong, so something to do with `\makeatletler`/`\makeatother` seems to be wrong. In the MWE all `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`s line up.

Comment: @moewe I found the cause of the problem: biblatex should be loaded after xpatch, not before it. So now your code is working perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Maras Mhhh, I have never heard that the load order of `biblatex` and `xpatch` would matter and in the MWE above it does not appear to be relevant. Can you upload an MWE where the order matters to a text-sharing website such as https://gist.github.com/ or https://pastebin.com/? I'd like to have a look. Maybe there is a bug/wrong assumption in `biblatex` that should be reported and fixed.

Comment: @moewe I tried hard to create MVE with philosophy-standart style, but I can't reproduce such behaviour. But it is consistent with my style and your MVE. So I can only sent all files of my style (it has other name), custom biblatex.cfg and maybe unofficial lithuanian.lbx (my style is in Lithuanian).
BTW, where can I read about meaning of some lbx strings (like about differences of editor and compilator) – I want create lithuanian.lbx

Comment: @Maras Can you show me your `biblatex.cfg`? (Upload it to https://gist.github.com/ or https://pastebin.com/). https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/03-localization-keys.tex contains a short explanation for each bibstring in the `.lbx` and many use cases in the bibliography (it could be that this particular version of the file throws errors for you because it is intended for use with the `dev` version of `biblatex`, in that case try the release version at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/03-localization-keys.tex). ...

Comment: ... If that doesn't help, just open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues.

Comment: @Maras I just had an idea. If you copy the code from the MWE into `biblatex.cfg` you should delete the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands. They are only required in the preamble of `.tex` files and are *not* needed in `.cfg` files (and can apparently cause errors that look quite similar to the one you got).

Comment: @moewe You were right – there are no more errors after deleting '\makeatletter' and '\makeatother' commands in '.cfg'. So  order of 'biblatex' and 'xpatch' were important only when code with '\makeatletter' and '\makeatother' were in the preamble, not in '.cfg'. Thank you for the help and links.